# Call bash from python on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, bash, powershell, subprocess

I've installed the Ubuntu component for Windows 10.

Within Ubuntu, I've installed tesseract. So in bash, I can run this command:

```
$ tesseract /mnt/c/Code/screenshot.png stdout
```

And it works.

In PowerShell, I can do this, and it also works:

```
PS> bash -c "tesseract /mnt/c/Code/screenshot.png stdout"
```

What isn't working is starting up Python 2.7.13 from Windows PowerShell and trying to call bash from it. I tried this at first:

```
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> check_output(['bash', '-c', 'tesseract /mnt/c/Code/screenshot.png stdout'])
```

That gives me: `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`.

If I reduce it down to just this:

```
>>> check_output(['bash'])
```

I get the same error.

```
>>> check_output(['bash'], shell = True)
```

Now I get: `'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Okay. Did a little bit of research on where the `bash.exe` is. I found it at `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`. But still this doesn't work:

```
>>> check_output([r'C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe'], shell = True)
```

But it just spits this out: `'C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

What's going on here? From a Python instance running on PowerShell on Windows 10, how can I invoke something in the copy of bash installed by the Ubuntu component for Windows 10?

Comment: You're running 32-bit Python, so System32 is redirected to SysWOW64, which doesn't have bash.exe. Either use 64-bit Python or `"C:\Windows\SysNative\bash.exe"`. "SysNative" is a virtual directory implemented for 32-bit WOW64 processes to run 64-bit system executables.

Comment: @eryksun - Perfect! Thank you!  Add that as an answer so I can accept and upvote it, please. (Seems like a massive shortcoming that the error message doesn't mention this at all... you just have to know that it's redirecting stuff and that you need to use  `SysNative` to actually reach `System32`...)

Comment: The behavior is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384274), so someone getting paid to build a 32-bit application that should run in 64-bit Windows should consider wading through docs just part of the job. For volunteers and hobbyists, it's understandably a pain to spend hours reading dry documentation before writing a single line of code.

Comment: @eryksun - I'd be willing to bet that precisely nobody at my company knows about this behavior (except me because you just told me.) This is an obscure factoid, not something that has ever come up in my decade+ of programming. Maybe a sys-admin kind of person would know about this. My biggest thought, as someone used to macOS, is "How is 32-bit vs 64-bit still a problem?"

Comment: Existing 32-bit programs should work without modification, and many of them are hard-coded, such as directly loading DLLs from System32. It could have been implemented differently, but I don't know all of the factors that went into the design decisions. I do know that the end result is that WOW64 is filled with sneaky magic and requires reading the docs to avoid surprises.

Comment: I find reading this webpage very helpful as well: http://www.samlogic.net/articles/32-64-bit-windows-folder-x86-syswow64.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was what Eryk Sun posted as a comment on the question:

> You're running 32-bit Python, so System32 is redirected to SysWOW64, which doesn't have bash.exe. Either use 64-bit Python or "C:\Windows\SysNative\bash.exe". "SysNative" is a virtual directory implemented for 32-bit WOW64 processes to run 64-bit system executables.